# Open Instagram with canvas generated image from a webapp

Tags: javascript, android, ios, web-applications, instagram-api

I'm building a webapp where you upload a photo and you can add custom emoticons to it (Like Facebook Stickers to photos, all this in a  element). The idea is that when you are done adding stickers you can share the photo to Instagram.

Is there a way to open Instagram app from mobile browsers (Android/iOS) with this picture ready to edit?
I've seen this functionality on some native apps (on iOS, they upload via airdrop) and it works but I found nothing about it on the API documentation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"Computer says no"

Also, there was already an answered question regarding this.
[is it possible to upload images from my web application to instagram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23951835/is-it-possible-to-upload-images-from-my-web-application-to-instagram)